# Does model maintains its structure when data is received in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure whether I've framed the question properly above in subject but I will try to explain to my best about the question I have.

I have below `ContactUsModel` which is a part of `HomeViewModel`, better say Nested Model Class in a single `model`

```
public class ContactUsDataModel
{
   public string ContactName { get; set; }
   public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
   public string ContactMessage { get; set; }
   public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

and I am getting this `Model` referred in `HomeViewModel` as below:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
   /*My other models goes here*/
   public ContactUsDataModel CUDModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now in `Index.cshtml` view I strongly create a form view as below:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.HomeViewModel
<!--I have other views for other models-->
@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactform" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CUDModel.ContactName, new { @class="contact col-md-6 col-xs-12", placeholder="Your Name *" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CUDModel.ContactEmail, new { @class = "contact noMarr col-md-6 col-xs-12", placeholder = "E-mail address *" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CUDModel.ContactPhone, new { @class = "contact col-md-12 col-xs-12", placeholder = "Contact Number (optional)" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.CUDModel.ContactMessage, new { @class = "contact col-md-12 col-xs-12", placeholder = "Message *" })
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="contact submit" value="Send message">
 }
```

I do `ajax` Post as below:

```
$('#contactform').on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formdata = new FormData($('.contact form').get(0));
   $.ajax({
            url: $("#contactform").attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            //success
            success: function (result) {
                //Code here
            },
            error: function (xhr,responseText,status) {
                //Code here
            }
    });
});
```

and in Controller I tried to receive it as below:

```
public JsonResult ContactPost(ContactUsDataModel model)
{
     var name=model.ContactName; //null
     /*Fetch the data and save it and return Json*/
     //model is always null
}
```

For some reason the above model is always `null`. But this works if I refer the `model` as `HomeViewModel model` instead of `ContactUsDataModel model` in controller parameter  like below:

```
public JsonResult ContactPost(HomeViewModel model)
{
     var name=model.CUDModel.ContactName; //gets value
     /*Fetch the data and save it and return Json*/
     //Model is filled.
}
```

> My question here is even though I fill `model` of type
>   `ContactUsDataModel` in the view I am getting it as `null` if I refer
>   directly, but `ContactUsModel` which is inside `HomeViewModel` gets
>   filled. Doesn't type of model matter here. Is the hierarchy its
>   referred is necessary while fetching in controller?

Comment: look at name attributes of inputs in the browser view source - that will tip you off

Comment: @haim770 I haven't tried that.. Will try it once..

Comment: Well name of the attribute will be kind of `CUDModel.ContactName` @Igor .. That makes sense since it is fetched from `homeviewmodel` but does it maintain same structure when it is posted.. That's what I am confused with..

Comment: So that's how it works in `MVC`? I mean structure-wise, it is as is maintained in all part of application? @haim770

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if your generated `<input>` name is `CUDModel.ContactName` instead of simply `ContactName`, the default Model-Binder wouldn't be able to bind it.

Fortunately, you can use the `[Bind]` attribute with prefix:

```
public JsonResult ContactPost([Bind(Prefix="CUDModel")]ContactUsDataModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Well this makes sense now.. I mean there  is some option to overcome it.. Wasn't aware of `Bind` much.. Thanks for sharing, I will implement this and if it goes well +15 for you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your web browser, inspect each DOM input element "name" property.  MVC automatically maps properties from your inputs to the class using the input's "name" property.

To solve this you can create a custom model binder or create the inputs by hand, specifying the name property in such a way that the automatic model binder can match them to properties of your class.

However, there isn't anything wrong with your controller action taking `HomeViewModel` as an argument.

More information, found [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx).

Comment: Well you link helped to understand some concepts, +1 for that, but it really did not solve my question... I also tried giving `name` as separate `html attribute` but model `overrided` it.. I will wait for some more time and see that if anyone comes up with proper explanation, otherwise will go and accept this as answer..  Thank you for your time and effort..

Answer (score 1):

Your view posts the Type you have referenced in the view - `@model ProjectName.Models.HomeViewModel` - `CUDModel` is simply a property of HomeViewModel.

Comment: I understand that part @viperguynaz, but I am confused with its structure.. Even though same model is filled why doesn't it accept it directly?

Comment: Because your view is strongly typed as a `HomeViewModel`

Comment: So it maintains its structure when posted irrespective of properties consisted in base model?

Comment: If your ViewModel was an `int` - it would post an `int`.